# Applying dynamically built expression on collection throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I have the following class:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Code { get; set; } 
}
```

I have a list of orders which, `List<Order>` of the expression type and when I apply the filter like [this](https://gist.github.com/ionuttamas/5c8cc546e3b27ecd977d):

```
var buildExpressionFilter = ExpressionQuery
            .Empty
            .WithType(typeof(Order)) 
            .AndContains("Code", "af")
            .GetResult();
Expression<Func<Order, bool>> normalFilter = x => x.Code.Contains("af");

var orders = GetOrders();
var result = orders.WhereByFilter(buildExpressionFilter).ToList(); //fails as shown below
var result2 = orders.WhereByFilter(normalFilter ).ToList(); //works ok
```

and **buildExpressionFilter** has the following properties:

Body: **{x => (True AndAlso x.Code.Contains("'af'"))}**

DebugView: **.Lambda #Lambda1(Artemis.Sample.Order $x) {
    True && .Call ($x.Code).Contains("'af'")
}**

and using an extension method which looks like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereByFilter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Expression filter)
        {
            dynamic dynamicFilter = filter;
            dynamic function = dynamicFilter.Compile();
            dynamic result = Enumerable.Where(collection, function); //CRASHES HERE

            return result;
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException : An unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, ref DynamicMetaObject deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder action, RuntimeBinder binder, IEnumerable`1 args, IEnumerable`1 arginfos, DynamicMetaObject onBindingError)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpInvokeBinder.FallbackInvoke(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
   at System.Dynamic.InvokeBinder.FallbackInvoke(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.InvokeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, LabelTarget returnLabel)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore(CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2<T0,T1>(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Artemis.Common.Collection.CollectionExtensions.WhereByFilter(IEnumerable`1 collection, Expression filter) in CollectionUtils.cs: line 25
```

Is obviously that buildExpressionFilter is not properly constructed, since calling with the regular filter works.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue? What may be wrong with my buildExpressionFilter?

Comment: Can you also post how do you construct your expression? Because without that code is hard to say is it correct or not....

Comment: Something similar to this one: https://gist.github.com/ionuttamas/5c8cc546e3b27ecd977d.

Comment: @Tamaslonut is there any additional information within `InnerException`?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev the InnerException is null.

Comment: @Tamaslonus, I'm unable to reproduce this issue. Did you make any changes to gist you use? Can you provide specific orders set on which error occurs?

Comment: Have any static constructors? If you do, put a breakpoint at the start and end of them and see if they're the cause. Also try to create a minimal test case please.

Answer (score 0):

I put the exact code you posted in your question and the GitHub link. The code is working fine in my example (although it doesn't handle `null` values for `Order.Code`). I tried framework versions `4.0`, `4.5`, `4.5.1.` and `4.5.2` and it worked fine on every one of them.

I believe you have made a modification to code posted in the GitHub page which is causing this error. This means I have no way to reproduce your problem.

I think you do not need to use dynamic invocation in the `WhereByFilter` implementation. This is because you appear to know `T` at compile time, in that case there is no reason to break type safety. That might clarify the error you are getting:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereByFilter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Expression<Func<T, bool>>  filter)
{
    var function = filter.Compile();
    return collection.Where(function);
}
```

Comment: The problem was due to the fact the for some reason or the other, different types of Order class were loaded and I was testing them in different projects.

Comment: The suggestions you've provided are useful, but were not the solution.